# Anyone know of a website for learning VBA in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, web, powerpoint, office-2003

I can do a few things with PowerPoint, but I need to learn more about the following:

- Adding a new textframe and text, and placing it where I want to on
  the slide.
- How to use VB to control the master slide.
- Add text to the notes field.

What resources and tutorials are available to help me with those items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfect for [beginning PowerPoint VBA](http://skp.mvps.org/index.html#newbie).

Comment: Top result in Google for "powerpoint vba", whodathunkit?

Comment: it's the common practice on SO for questions like these.

Comment: sorry...it's just that i am so much of a beginner at this i would rather be directed by those of experience (like yourselves) to the right place, instead of wasting time.

i am looking for some very simple things really...inserting a text box into ppt...and trying to figure out how in the world you can find the "name" of an object ("text box 93") ot ("rectangle 4").....i can only seem to do this by recording a mcr, and the viewing it to find the "name" of the object i want to work with...

thanks again!

Comment: bare in mind that "name" property values for Shapes in office applications are not necessarily unique values. You can quite easily get duplicates. If you are iterating for a value in a loop you'll need to use the ID property to avoid working with dupes.

Answer (score 0):

To find names and such
Select a shape and step through this macro and highlight or watch the variables for values

Sub Shape_name()

Let x = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name

Let y = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Type

Let Z = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Id

Let a = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).OLEFormat.ProgID

Let b = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Height

Let c = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Width

Let D = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Left

Let E = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top

End Sub